# Javascript to build HTML

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

this one may be simple but it has eluded me. I have Javascript code which builds elements in the DOM (using JSON from a server script). Some of the elements have "onclick" calls that I want to pass the ID variable to.

I cannot seem to get the `onclick="downloadImg("' + d.data_id + '")"` syntax right. What should it be. The code below does not work. Thanks.

```
temp_html = temp_html + '<img src="/link/to/img.png" onclick="downloadImg("' + d.data_id + '")">';
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way. Take a look at [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) and avoid all the syntax problems by adding the handler directly to the element.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the double quotations, you will close the previous one, so you create a conflict. So replace `"` with a single quotation + escape `\'` like this:

```
temp_html = temp_html + '<img src="/link/to/img.png" onclick="downloadImg(\'' + d.data_id + '\')">';
```

Comment: Hey, seems we had the same idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Your line should be:

```
temp_html = temp_html + '<img src="/link/to/img.png" onclick="downloadImg(\\"' + d.data_id + '\\")">';
```

You basically have many layers of quotes so the 
   double slash
creates a 
   \" 
in the output that escapes the quote once it gets outputted to HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="/link/to/img.png" onclick="downloadImg("' + d.data_id + '")">';
```

This will resolve to something like: `<img src="/link/to/img.png" onclick="downloadImg("1")">`

As you can see you have double quotes inside double quotes. Something like this should do it:

```
<img src="/link/to/img.png" onclick="downloadImg(\'' + d.data_id + '\')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your double quotes to single quotes and escape them:

`onclick="downloadImg(\'' + d.data_id + '\')"`